# yii error on adding data to DB

Tags: php, yii

```
include(label.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
(/Applications/AMPPS/www/framework-1.1.17/YiiBase.php:432)
```

I am getting the above error on yii1 storing data. Below is my model file and controller function to add data to DB. Am I missing something in this?

```
<?php
 class account extends CoreModel {

public function tableName() {
    return 'account';
}

public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('id', 'label', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'required'),
        array('id', 'integer'),
        array('created_at', 'updated_at', 'safe'),
        array('label', 'string', 'max' => 20),
    );
}
public function attributeLabels() {
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'label' => 'Label',
        'created_at' => 'Created At',
        'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
    );
}
 }
```

Controller function:

```
function saveDetails(){
    $abc = new Account();

    $abc->id = Yii::app()->user->id;
    $abc->label = "Test";
    $abc->save();
    echo "done";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I think the attribute list in the first rule should be in the same string like ("id, label,created_at,updated", "required"). Check the docs http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#rules-detail

Comment: @RamKesavan I am tried changing the name, but facing the same issue.

Comment: class account extends CoreModel (simple case 'accounts') vs new Account() (upper case) could be your problem

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
array('id', 'label', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'required'),
```

to this:

```
array(array('id', 'label', 'created_at', 'updated_at'), 'required'),
```

Same here:

```
array('created_at', 'updated_at', 'safe'),
```

to:

```
array(array('created_at', 'updated_at'), 'safe'),
```

But you dont need to specify `created_at` and `updated_at` as `safe`, because they occurs in `required` rule.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `$abc->label` is triggering an autoload request for some reason. Probably due to a conflicting library. You could use `CActiveRecord`'s `setAttributes()` and rewrite like this to eliminate magic method/property calls and autoload confusions.

Controller function

```
function saveDetails(){
    $abc = new Account();
    $abc->setAttributes([
        'id' => Yii::app()->user->id,
        'label' => "Test"
    ]);
    $abc->save();
    echo "done";
    //exit;
    Yii::app()->end(); // This is the clean exit from a Yii app.
}
```